# Create csv file after looping through array in php

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have looped through an array and can successfully print out the rows that I need to work with

```
foreach($array['Stock'] as $row) {
    echo '|' . $row['Code'] . '|' . intval($row['Onhand']) . "\r\n";
}
```

I need to have all of the printed rows to be saved in a csv file. Should I be converting to an array first and then creating a csv or can I do it from within the loop?

Just to clarify guys, the file requirements are

*'This CSV file must contain 3 columns, separated by the pipe symbol (|), without
column names. '*

Comment: it looks like you are delimiting each row with a pipe `|` for a csv I would have expected to see a comma used. Will add an answer but could you clarify this please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepend each row onto a variable like:

```
$csv .= $row['Code'] . ',' . intval($row['Onhand']) . "\r\n";
```

Then use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) to save to local file, or use [header](http://php.net/header) to output headers to force download to browser.

**PS:** CSV stands for comma separated values, not pipe separated values, so if I'm correct in assuming you're using the pipe `|` to separate values it's best to use a comma instead.

Comment: damn beat me to it +1 for the comma seperated values as opposed to pipe